# Error while running maven project for elasticsearch in Intelij Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, elasticsearch, pom.xml

Hi I am trying to write a simple program to implement a elastic search client. I am using Intellij Idea IDE and maven for that.

I have created a maven project, and under ~/Desktop/ESearch/src/main/java/dhruv/dev/elastic, I have created the following java file.

I just want to try to retrieve the result through elasticsearch GET - API. I have already indexed using REST-API, and can retrieve them using marvel plugin.

```
package dhruv.dev.elastic;

import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node;
import java.io.IOException;
import static org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder;

public class ESClient
{
    public static void search()throws IOException
    {
        Node node;
        node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("Pikachu").node();
        Client client;
        client = node.client();
        GetResponse response;
        response= client.prepareGet("twitter", "tweet", "1").execute() .actionGet();
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        search();

    }

}
```

In my pom.xml , the following code is there,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dhruv</groupId>
    <artifactId>Search</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The code is compiling fine. When I run it , it gives errors like :-

> > BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> >     ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
> >  [INFO] Total time: 5.319s [INFO] Finished at: Tue May 19 19:39:31
> >     IST 
> >   2015 [ INFO ] Final Memory: 12M/220M [INFO]
> >     ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
> > [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> >     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
> >     (default-deploy) on project Search: Deployment failed: repository
> >     element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement
> >     element

What exactly is that , I am unable to figure out. I read about it a little [here](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) but how does it relate to my project as it is just for practice not for deployment. I know that I may be sounding stupid but I am unable to get any concrete idea about it.

Comment: why are you trying to deploy it in the first place? If you just want to retrieve the result, just run it.

Comment: I just want to run it. But it is not showing any such option.

Comment: try ..main(String args[ ]) ..

Comment: by the way why was this necessary?